# Loading image using retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to develop an android app where user can  see their profile icon in league of legends: http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/profileicon/588.png

The number at the end of the image corresponds to the skin number.
My plan is to get user input and store it to variable called profileIconId and it will look
like this

```
http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/profileicon/{profileIconId}.png
```

So, my interface look like this:

```java
Call<SummonerData> getIcon(@Path("profileIconId") int profileIconId);
```

I tried doing this, but I failed. Is there a better way to get the image?

I tried combining Glide to load the image but still failed

```java
Call<SummonerData> callimg = lolAPI.getIcon(summonerData.getProfileIconId());
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()
).load(callimg)
.into(profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing basic string concatenation. But I'm pretty sure there is a better way of solving this.I insert the user input to the link and converted it to string.

```
            SummonerData summonerData =response.body();
            String displayDetails;
            displayDetails =    "Name: " + summonerData.getName() +"\n" +
            "Level: " + summonerData.getSummonerLevel()+"\n" +
            "Profileicon:" + summonerData.getProfileIconId();
            details_summoner.setText(displayDetails);
            int profileIcon = summonerData.getProfileIconId();
            String stringNumber = Integer.toString(profileIcon);
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()
            ).load("https://raw.communitydragon.org/latest/plugins/rcp-be-lol-game- data/global/default/v1/profile-icons/" +
            stringNumber +
            ".jpg")
            .into(profile);
```